# How to fix the error C2371: 'RGBQUAD': redefinition; different basic types

Tags: c, rgb, gdi

I'm coding in C and using GDI. When trying to use RGBQUAD, this errors happens:

```
C2371: 'RGBQUAD': redefinition; different basic types
```

Here's my code (it's a header):

```
typedef union
{
    COLORREF rgb;
    struct
    {
        BYTE b;
        BYTE g;
        BYTE r;
        BYTE unused;
    };
} RGBQUAD, * PRGBQUAD;
```

Comment: There's a problem with your `#include`s: maybe you're including incompatible versions of Windows SDKs, or maybe you're defining macros in a way that Windows doesn't expect. Try reviewing your `#include`s and your project settings and systematically simplify them until you've isolated the source of the error.

Comment: Note that anything that #includes "Windows.h" will (itself) define `RGBQUAD` as a data type.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how I could simplify my #include s because I only have one. It's pointing out on another header file (neuranium.h) where I defined RGBQUAD, along with including all of my header files

Comment: Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: You should not redefine any types from WinAPI. Use different name (and certainly not uppercase) and use your own namespace prefix. All type names in C must be globally unique.